# How old was Haman in the Megillah?

Tags: purim, age, haman

I'm on a bit of a quest to contextualize the story of Purim by getting a better sense of the ages of the main characters. So far, with Mi Yodeya's help, I've explored the [age of Esther](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22833/3388), and I have also discovered a [suggested age of Mordechai](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100719/3388).

Are there any textual sources in Midrashic or later literature which provide an age for Haman during the Purim story?

Comment: I think there's an opinion that Haman and Mordechai were the same age.