# How old was Vashti in the Megillah?

Tags: megillat-esther, age

We’ve previously discussed how old [Esther](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22832/), [Mordechai](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100678/), [Haman](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100720/), and [Achashveirosh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100721/) were at the time of the Megillah.

How old was Vashti when she was summoned to Achashveirosh?

Comment: ומה נ"מ? So you found someone saying she was young - then what? How does it influence the course of the events? Maybe you can combine those questions into one - the Megillah Trivia.

Comment: @AlBerko Not every (non-Halachic) question needs to have a Nafka Minah. Sometimes, questions are asked purely for curiosity’s sake.

Answer (score 3):

Yalkut Shimoni, Nach 1049 says that Vashti was 12-12.5 when Belshazzar died:

> וכשהמלכו דריוש אותה הלילה בלשאצר שהיו אלו הורגים ואלו בוזזים ושתי היתה נערה
>
> And when they made Daryavesh king, that night Belshatzar - some of them were killing [him] and some of them were looting him. Vashti was a Na’arah.

Megillah 11b says that Achashveirosh ascended the throne five years later:

> חדא דבלשצר וחמש דדריוש וכורש ותרתי דידיה
>
> One year for Belshatzar, five years for Daryavesh and Koresh, and two years of [Achashveirosh’s, which were followed by the party].

Combining these two pieces, it follows that Vashti was roughly 19-19.5 when the feast started, and roughly 19.5-20 when she was killed.

Comment: It’s not certain that Vashti was executed. According to some commentators, Vashti was banished.